pom file for selenium-devtools-v119 is not available in MavenCentral

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v119:jar:4.16.0: Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v119:pom:4.16.0

Is there a way to exclude this dependency in pom.xml? or should I update to any particular version in my pom.xml to resolve this issue.
We are using the below version in pom.xml file
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

